# can`t use three.js texture loader in javascript worker

Tags: javascript, three.js, web-worker

I'm trying to use three.js to load the texture.

main.js:

```
const worker = new Worker('../workers/worker.js', {
    type: 'module'
  });
```

and this is the simple worker.js:

```
    import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js';
 const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    textureLoader.load(
      // resource URL
      'images/texture.jpg',
    
      // onLoad callback
      function ( texture ) {
        // in this example we create the material when the texture is loaded
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
          map: texture
         } );
      },
    
      // onProgress callback currently not supported
      undefined,
    
      // onError callback
      function ( err ) {
        console.error( 'An error happened.' );
      }
    );
```

But I get following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

In my searches, I got it there is no way to access the DOM but I don't know how I can fix that, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue by using [THREE.ImageBitmapLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=imagebit#api/en/loaders/ImageBitmapLoader) instead of `THREE.TextureLoader`. This new type of loader has no dependency to the DOM.

There is also an [official example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_imagebitmap) that demonstrate the loader. The basic usage is:

```js
const loader = new THREE.ImageBitmapLoader();
loader.load( 'path/to/my/texture.png', function ( imageBitmap ) {

        const texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture( imageBitmap );
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );

} );
```